# Magmi product import with image attributes processor can't find images

Tags: import, product-images, magmi

When I do a magmi import all works excluding my images, I get the error:
"M0467-RS.jpg cannot be found in images path"

I have put them in media/import of the root magento installation and the Filesystem Path to magento directory is correct.

In the config of image attributes processor I have put media/import
also tried /media/import and /media/import/.

The directory and all subdirectories of media are 777

I have tried saving the .csv in notepad++ to make sure encoding is correct.
I have checked filenames in the .csv

the .csv has columns image, thumbnail, small_image and media_gallery and these are populated with images respectively:

M0467-RS.jpg

M0467-RS.jpg

M0467-RS.jpg

M0467-HS.jpg;M0467-RS.jpg;M0467-SW.jpg;M0467-CL.jpg;M0467-EX.jpg

the file M0467-RS.jpg definitely exists as I can see it in FTP and access it via URL.

despite all of this magmi STILL can't find the images (M0467-RS.jpg cannot be found in images path).

I am using magmi version 0.7.23
and magento version 1.9.x

Comment: Magmi source code is readily available. Reopening as on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

put plus sign (+) before images. I have the same problem and this resolved it. This is my csv file:
sku,image,small_image,thumbnail,media_gallery
test,+test.png,+test.png,+test.png,/Untitled-8.jpg;/Untitled-10.jpg;/Untitled-12.jpg

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate, in what way could this help?

Comment: http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-image-attributes-processor/

Comment: Hi Sorry, this isn't helpful to the problem, the import actually gives an error saying it cant find my images, it's nothing to do with the base images not being set in the gallery

Comment: Wot no answer box? Here is my answer: try changing the file names to lower case and then also to lower case in the import csv file. If that doesn't work hack into the MAGMI code to try to find out the paths MAGMI is using. Did you re-ask this question outside the Magento forum? I can't find it to put in code listings. Anyway, in magmi folder seek `/plugins/extra/itemprocessors/imageprocessor/imageiyattributeemprocessor.php` and look in function `public function copyImageFile($imgfile, &$item, $extra)` here you can sprinkle some `$this->log()` and eventually I hard-coded $source and $l2d here.